# Can't format my layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to place a `LinearLayout` with a banner ad - at the bottom of a `RelativeLayout`.

I'm trying to achieve it by:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".AllJokes" >

    <ListView
              android:id="@+id/allJokesList"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:id="@+id/adViewContainer"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

              <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But it always gives me this error:

```
error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

I know that my formatting is completely messed up, but I can't find a way to make it valid.

I just need a clue, as I'm a total beginner at android and xml. I'm missing something really small I know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the below in the root element of xml layout

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

Like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

coz you have

```
ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID" // see this attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a trailing '>' for your LinearLayout. So that part should be:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:id="@+id/adViewContainer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```